# How to create relationship between two collections in mongodb. I'm using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, database-design

'm trying to create a relationship between user and contestant collection. Want to be able to get contestants created by a particular user using the users id. And i'm using typescript.

userSchema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 8
},
role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["Admin", "User"],
    required:true
},
company: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
contestName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  image: {
    type: String
  }
}, {timestamps: true});

export default mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

contestantSchema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const contestantSchema = new Schema({
  fname: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
lname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
vote: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
},
user_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
 }
}, {timestamps: true});

export default mongoose.model("Contestant", contestantSchema);
```

THE ROUTE:
this is the route that i want to use to call the data

```
router.get("/contestants", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
   const user = await Contestant.find()
   .sort({createdAt: 1})
   .populate("user_id")

    res.json(user)
   } catch (err: any) {
     console.error(err.message);
     res.status(500).send("Server error");
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `ref` attribute as what you set for the model name of the schema that you reference to.

(`mongoose.model("User", userSchema);`)

In this case you should set `ref` attribute as `ref: 'User'` not `ref: 'users'`